# Read PEM certificate and private key with powershell

Tags: python, php, powershell, ssl-certificate

I need to access a web api from Power Automate. There's one step that I'll need to outsource to an Azure runbook, either PowerShell or Python as it is not supported by PowerAutomate.

I need to create an authentication object using a nonce, apikey and an X509 certificate. I have all of these. The only information I have for this is a PHP code:

```
// Create signed authentication message
$certificate = openssl_x509_read(file_get_contents($certPath));
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($keyPath);
openssl_x509_export($certificate, $certificate);
$auth = json_encode(array(
            "nonce" => $nonce->result,
            "apikey" => $apiKey,
            "certificate" => $certificate
        ));
$signature = null;
if(!openssl_sign($auth, $signature, $privateKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256))
{
    die('Could not sign');
}
$message = array(
        "authentication" => $auth,
        "signature" => base64_encode($signature)
    );
$context = stream_context_create(array(
        "http" => array(
                "method" => "POST",
                "content" => json_encode($message),
                "header" => "Content-Type: application/json"
            )
));
```

Text instructions are

Create an authentication object and sign the JSON-formatted object with the RSA key.

I have both the certificate and the private key as pem file and the nonce too. Imported the certificate in PowerShell as:

```
$Cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$Cert.Import($certpath)
```

I cannot import the private key pem file the same way as it fails with `Exception calling "Import" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot find the requested object.`
Based on some research, I need to read this file somehow into an X509Certificate2 object then create the private key object with the GetRSAPrivateKey command like

```
$privatekey = ([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions]::GetRSAPrivateKey($key))
```

The certificate file only contents the certificate and the key file only the private key, including the begin/end tags.

Can somebody please help me to find the read of the private key and the sign command equivalents in PowerShell (or Python)?